# Possible Solutions to Poor Serialization Performance

Tags: .net, asp.net, performance, serialization, reflection

I recently did some performance testing and analysis of an ASP.NET application using out-of-process session state - this is necessary when using session state on a web farm so that state can be retrieved on any of the web servers, e.g. if subsequent HTTP requests arrive at a different server because the sessions aren't 'sticky' or the original server is down, etc.

What surprised me was that when I ran the web servers at full load and profiled the CPU usage something like 99% of CPU time was spent serializing and deserializing session state. Subsequently we implemented a customised 'caching' state server; this always serializes state but also keeps state in-memory so that if you use sticky sessions the state doesn't have to be deserialized most of the time. This improved server throughput by a factor of 2; However, serialization still makes up 98% or more of CPU time.

We obtained some further improvements in speed by 'trimming' unnecessary object references between objects in the session state prior to serialization - fixing up the references manually upon desrialization. This improved speed by another 10-20% or so. The reasoning here is that some of the performance loss is due to the built in serialization having to walk the graph of object pointers, which becomes a more complex task with more pointers.

Continuining the investigation we wrote customized serialization routines for some of our classes rather than relying on .Net's built-in serialization. What we found was that performance was **greatly improved**, by a factor of about **50x**. It seems the bulk of the CPU load is caused by built in .Net serialization, which in turn is slow due to reliance on using Reflection to walk the object pointers/graph and extract field data.

It's very tempting to boost our performance by 50x, thus reducing the web server hardware requirements by a large factor (and power requirements by a lesser but still significant factor). The options currently are:

1) Write customized serialization. This is an issue due to the complexity of the task and the maintenance overhead it generates, that is, any change to class state requires a change to the serialization/deserialization routines.

2) Some third party solution. Perhaps some product that automatically generates state save/load code at build time, thus eliminating the need to use Reflection.

I'd be very interested to know if anyone knows of a third party solution, or has encountered this issue as I haven't found any mention of it from internet searches.

UPDATE:
Some have suggested a sort of halfway solution between the default built-in serialization and pure customized serialization routines. The idea is that you implement customized serialization for the classes that affect performance the most by, e.g. overiding ISerializable. This is an interesting and promising approach; However I still think there's scope for a complete replacement for built-in serialization without having to write and maintain any custom code - this can't be done at runtime because Reflection is needed to query objects and access private data. But it is theoretically possible to post-process already built assemblies and inject new methods as an additional build step. Some profilers use this approach to inject profiling code into assemblies after they have been built by the C# compiler. Also I /think/ I read somewhere that the .Net framework supports injecting methods into classes - thus all the messing around with IL is potentially taken care of.

Comment: Pretty sure the injecting methods you are talking about would be the use of partial classes. I think the principle is if two classes in the same namespace have the same name and one is marked as partial. One dll is produced incorporating methods and properties from both classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I am only aware of option one and tbh that can start to get very painful to work on.

But it does only what you want so it's as quick as it gets.

Good luck.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer because we found that all other solutions are at least 10x slower than writing customized code.

Answer (score 1):

One other option is to aggressively disable ViewState on all controls that are not touched on server side postbacks.

Comment: Much of the state is from our own classes, but yes there will be state from built standard ASP.NET controls so that's definitely worth keeping an eye on. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can partially customize your serialization by implementing `ISerializable`.  If you do this for the worst offenders, you won't increase maintenance as much but will still get some of the speedup.

Comment: I wanted to add that in our tests recently we found that this disn't improve performance. It appears that the performance hit is from the code that walks the object graph - the actual data handling is not the slow bit!

Answer (score 1):

There is a third-party solution:

Simon Hewitt's excellent open source library, see [Optimizing Serialization in .NET - part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/dotnet/OptimizingSerialization2.asp).

I am [using it in my application](http://pmortensen.eu/1/MSQuant/MSQsrcWWW,1.5,2008-12-19/MSQdocDefs.vb.html) and got a similar speed-up
as you, 20-40 times.

It eliminates the reflection that is the cause of the
slowdown, but for lists it only supports a few native types.
So for Genreric.List's of your own types there needs to be
explicit code somewhere or the other. E.g. explicit loops or
something smarter that automates this. In any case it is
pretty simple and should not be hindrance for the huge
benefits.

Comment: Thanks, lots of interesting info here. At first glance it appears to be positioned halfway between using built in (slow) and pure customised serialization. It piggy-backs on the built in serialzation which was also suggested by one of the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

We have encountered similar issues and have devised several ways of improving performance. We use some of these in our Persistore memory mapping product (currently beta). In our case we can simply access persisted data "in situ" because it is always in a memory mapped heap.

However, one 'trick' is to define your session state data (if possible) as *marshalable* class/struct and 'serialize' that using .NET marshalling support, this can be very fast indeed but won't handle 'object' graphs.

We also support a special persistence based on Binary serialization, but we also extract and persist metadata so that managed code can set/get fields within a memory persisted datum at runtime without the need to deserialize the whole object, this is useful in some settings (e.g securities and stock price updates etc). Our latest beta supports serialization across a network, of LINQ *anonymous types*, this is a first so far as I am aware.

Anyway, we'd be interested to have some new beta customers who are pushing ASP.NET and web performance issues, our latest beta is very impressive (but not ready until nex week).

If anyone is curious just contact us for the latest info on the product.

Hugh Moran

PS: Website is out of date, the product goes far beyond what is described there.